# How can i post selected images to web link by using json parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, uiimage

Im my iphone app i want to post image to a link. That image is selecting from phone gallery. I converted that image to nsstring. But i have an error at posting.

Error is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x9e599a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"
)

I'm using below codes

for converting image to string:

```
CGFloat compression = 0.25f;

NSData *imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image, compression);

profileObj.profileImageString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:imagedata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
profileObj.profileImageString = [profileObj.profileImageString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"profileObj.profileImageString: %@",profileObj.profileImageString);
```

for posting to link:

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

ProfileObject *profile_obj=obj;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@upload/register/john@gmail.com/password/774e4b7b118994b1c58d71c088834d43ca2937623319f6b7b6c48a1846132027/iPhone/1/%@",MainUrl,profile_obj.profileImageString]];

NSLog(@"url is---%@",url);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSError* error = nil;

NSURLResponse* response;

NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *dataString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableDictionary *getResponseDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[getResponseDict addEntriesFromDictionary:[dataString JSONValue]];
NSString  *responseStr=[getResponseDict objectForKey:@"message"];
NSLog(@"responseStr is....%@",responseStr);
return responseStr;
```

sorry I'm poor in english   Don't mind that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out my ans, same problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524323/converting-image-to-base64-and-uploading-in-json-format-to-server/14605101#14605101

it will work for u.

Answer (score 1):

You could always base64 encode the image data.

This makes sure you got the right string in a post.

You could use extensions like this: http://svn.cocoasourcecode.com/MGTwitterEngine/NSData+Base64.m to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For image posting

```
NSString  *imgPath = fullPathOfYourImage;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imgPath])
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];                                                        
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"YourImageName.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                                                                                                               ^..YourImageName….^

        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imgPath]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
```