# Uploading an image in base64 string format to the server

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I encoded the base64 image string using CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes:

```
(__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)imageString, NULL,CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

This works. But now that 
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes is deprecated and it is recommended to use stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters, I am not sure what allowed character set to use. I tried each one of the following sets with the above characters included, but none is working:

```
@interface NSCharacterSet (NSURLUtilities)
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLUserAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLHostAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLPathAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet;
@end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you uploading the image by placing the data in the url? Because that's a bad idea, you should put it in the body, that way you won't need to escape the url.

Comment: And a base64 string shouldn't need any percent escapes.

Comment: No, I didn't place it in the url, I put it in http body using setHTTPBody.

Comment: I also set the header like: [request setValue:self.authorization forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/octet-stream" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"base64" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];

Comment: I did the encoding similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524323/converting-image-to-base64-and-uploading-in-json-format-to-server

Comment: I finally got this working by removing certain characters rather than adding them: [charSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
            [charSet removeCharactersInString:@":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"];